# Android Bluetooth-Is it possible to construct the Bluetooth Device by using the given MAC Address,Serial Number and Device's PIN?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am creating an android application in which I have list out the Bluetooth devices which the user has added recently and my requirement is if the user going to login with some other mobile device there also i display the already paired Bluetooth devices Here if the Bluetooth device is enabled with the PIN pairing option I have got the all the detail of the Bluetooth device like MAC Address,Serial No and PIN details here what i want to do is in the background itself while getting the list of devices from the server i need to do the PIN pairing for d particular device I mean here I don't need to wait for the device presence from the given details i need to create the BluetoothDevice Object.

Comment: You can get the mac adress of paried and discovered devices too.
Take at the BluetoothDevice class. And check out the developer guide for bluetooth too.

Comment: @VikingPingvin My requirement is need to construct a Bluetooth device from the given MAC,serial no and PIN

Comment: I am not expert in the topic, but i have created a bluetooth app that can pair and communicate two-way with a microcontroller.
Bluetooth discovery lists you Devices, you can query their Mac adress, that is enough completely to start an RFsocket. As far as i know, PIN is only used when pairing, which is done with the built in OS pairing, outside of your application. You can also create an rfsocket WITHOUT pairing a device. Aboput serial no, i have no clue sorry. Hope this helped a little.
EDIT: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN

Answer (score 0):

I assume your app is want to let user to migrate the paired device smoothly between different devices. If you are building your app on Android, I mean fi you do not hijack(get the root privilege) the system, the answer is NO. You can only got the MAC address, but you can not get the PIN(here the PIN I assume should be the linkkey/LTK which is used for encrypt the link).If the PIN here is pincode, it is meaningless since the pin code may vary, and only used for pairing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually here the PIN is nothing but the serial number for the particular device.when we pair the device we send those information to the server then we will get those information in the paired device list.

Comment: Okay, How can i do this? I get the list of devices with details from the service and here i don't have the physical Bluetooth presence of all the devices which i have received from the server.I need to construct the Bluetooth device and do the PIN pairing in background and it doesn't matter whether the device's Bluetooth is off or on.

Comment: sorry I do not understand your description, can you clarify your detailed requests, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.Actually while i try to swap the Bluetooth Devices say for example user 1 has logged in with a mobile device A and then he has paired 5 BLE devices with PIN pairing here I will update the BLE Devices Information to the server and then user 1 Logged out from the mobile device A and He logged in with device B  and here i got the list of user devices from the server and here while i am parsing the device response i need to pair all the 5 devices with the given devices detail.

Comment: OK, your app can read the the paired bluetooth address via getAddress(and other information e.g. cod, you also need monitor new paired device) and submit to server, after you downloaded the device info to B, you might as well scan the device and if found they can be connected just pair with them.

Comment: Thanks..i think you didn't understand my question anyway I convince my client about this.

Comment: a draft picture would help this I think.